# How can I solve this? How can I fix the fatal error?

Tags: swift, error-handling, fatal-error

This is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    refresh()
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let users = objects {
            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.userids.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            for object in users {
                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    if user.objectId! != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {
                        self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                        self.userids.append(user.objectId!)
                        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers")
                        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
                            print("currentUser() is nil");
                        } else if (PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId == nil) {
                            print("PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId is nil");
                        } else if (user.objectId == nil) {
                            print("user.objectId is nil");
                        }
                        query.whereKey("follower",equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)
                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                            if let objects = objects {
                                if objects.count > 0 {
                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                                } else {
                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false
                                }
                            }
                            if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Whenever I try to run this piece of code, I get an error on the line which says "query.whereKey" that prints to the logs like this:

> nilPFUser.currentUser()!.objectId is nilfatal error: unexpectedly
>   found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why is that? How can I fix it? I need help on this one. Be specific. 
Thank you.

Again, it unexpectedly found a nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: You are trying to explicitly unwrap optional here: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId! it means that currentUser or objectId is nil. By using ! you saying that you are sure it's nor a nil.

Comment: So what should I do specifically? @CouchDeveloper

Comment: Whenever I remove those !'s, I just get errors

Comment: @EliasWettersteinRoennow As Greg suggests, you need to explicitly consider the case that `PFUser.currentUser()` may also return `nil`. You might use `if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {...} else {...}`